# Bundle and run JavaScript module in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to run a JavaScript module with external dependencies in the browser. Is that possible? I know that Babel can be executed in the browser, so that should be possible.

Let's say that I have a following module:

```
const module = `
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

    ReactDOM.render(<div>Hello, world!</div>, document.body);
`
```

Now, how to „compile” it so that it can be executed in the browser? Also, the tricky part is that I want to preserve versions, so let's say that I want to use version `16` of React and ReactDOM.

Comment: Learn about JavaScript modules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: Plus something like https://esm.sh/.

Comment: Do you mean that I can just insert dynamically a script tag with type of module and things should just work?

Comment: You need to provide the source code of `react` and `react-dom` (and any other possibly imported libraries) somehow. But then yes, it would be possible.

Comment: @Bergi I will try to use esm.sh for that. Thanks!